# Unsigned arithmetic and integer overflow

Tags: c++, c, long-integer, integer-overflow, integer-arithmetic

I am trying to understand arithmetic overflow. Suppose I have the following,

```
unsigned long long x;
unsigned int y, z;

x = y*z;
```

y*z can lead to an integer overflow. Does casting one of the operands to an unsigned long long alleviate this issue. What is the expected result of the multiplication of a 64-bit operand with a 32-bit operand?

Comment: Both operands are promoted to the wider type first if they're not of equal type.

Comment: From many examples I can tell it uses the bigger type for the result. So yeah, casting one of the operands will solve the problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That doesn't apply in this case. `y` and `z` are both `unsigned int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: No (I think I said that?), that was just in response to the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unsigned long long x;
unsigned int y, z;

x = y*z;
```

The evaluation of the expression `y*z` is not affected by the context in which it appears. It multiplies two `unsigned int` values, yielding an `unsigned int` result. If the mathematical result cannot be represented as an `unsigned int` value, the result will wrap around. The assignment then implicitly converts the (possibly truncated) result from `unsigned int` to `unsigned long long`.

If you want a multiplication that yields an `unsigned long long` result, you need to explicitly convert one or both of the operands:

```
x = (unsigned long long)y * z;
```

or, to be more explicit:

```
x = (unsigned long long)y * (unsigned long long)z;
```

C's `*` multiplication operator applies *only* to two operands of the same type. Because of this, when you give it operands of different types, they're converted to some common type before the multiplication is performed. The rules can be a bit complex when you're mixing signed and unsigned types, but in this case if you multiply an `unsigned long long` by an `unsigned int`, the `unsigned int` operand is promoted to `unsigned long long`.

*If* `unsigned long long` is at least twice as wide as `unsigned int`, as it is on most systems, then the result will neither overflow nor wrap around, because, for example, a 64-bit `unsigned long long` can hold the result of multiplying any two 32-bit `unsigned int` values. But if you're on a system where, for example, `int` and `long long` are both 64 bits wide, you can still have <strike>overflow</strike> wraparound, giving you a result in `x` that's not equal to the mathematical product of `y` and `z`.

Answer (score 5):

You are clearly assuming that `unsigned int` is 32-bit and `unsigned long long` 64-bit. They don't have to be, be let us assume this.

A 64-bit operand that was obtain by converting a 32-bit operand still fits in 32 bits. Thus in `y*(unsigned long long)z`, where each of the operands is first promoted to `unsigned long long`, the result is computed as an `unsigned long long` and cannot “overflow”, because it is the multiplication of two quantifies that fit in 32 bits each.

(Also, in the vocabulary of the C standard, unsigned operations do not “overflow”. Overflowing is the undefined behavior of producing a result outside the bounds of the destination type. What unsigned operations do is “wrap around”).

Answer (score 3):

If one operand is wider than the other, the compiler should be (or behave as if it is) converting both operands to the same size, so casting one to a larger size will produce the correct behaviour.

This is specified in the C and C++ standards. The C++11 standard (n3337 draft) has this to say, in chapter five, statement 9:

> ... if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion
>   rank shall be converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.

There is a couple of pages describing all the conversions and stuff that goes on, but this is what defines this particular expression's behaviour.

Comment: This isn't the compiler's fault, though. The language demands this behaviour.

Comment: Yes, wording altered to reflect this and quote from standard document provided.

Comment: Beautiful. Once we have the wording from the standard, it's almost like we never need to talk about compilers at all :-) (The subject is already way too complicated as it is, without bringing in all the periphery!)

Comment: How does that apply in this case? Both `y` and `z` are of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The OP asks if casting one value to `unsigned long long` helps.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You're right, I hadn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: @KeithThompson: No worries, it is lacking 50% of the question marks that an English speaker would expect, which I consider particularly bad form.

Comment: So, the compiler isn't involved? Is the standard doing it just by existing?